# C coding- Display 1 digit to the right of the decimal, unless the digit is a 0, then don't display any decimal places

Tags: decimal, precision

I am trying to display only one digit to the right of the decimal place unless that digit is a 0, then there would be no decimal place displayed. I am a beginner and I cannot use any complicated coding or conditional statements. This is my current code but it will not display any decimal places in any case.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#define PI 3.1415927

int main()

{

//Local Declarations
float radius;
float volume;
float SA;
float height;
int dec;
int Dec;
int dec1;
int dec2;
int Dec1;
int Dec2;

//Statements
printf("Enter the radius: ");
scanf("%f", &radius);

height = radius;
volume =  PI * pow( radius, 2.0) * height;
SA = (2.0 * PI * pow( radius, 2.0)) + (2.0 * PI * radius * height);
dec = (volume - (int)volume) * 10.0;
dec1= 0.1 * (int)dec;
dec2 = (dec1 + 2) % (dec1 + 1);
Dec = (SA - (int)SA) * 10.0;
Dec1 = 0.1 * (int)Dec;
Dec2 = (Dec1 + 2) % (Dec1 + 1);

//Output
printf("\n-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=");
printf("\nVolume:              %.*f\n",dec2, volume);
printf("Surface Area:         %.*f\n",Dec2, SA);
printf("-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=");

return 0;

} //main
```

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring your dec variables as integers. You should use float instead. Any operation cast to an integer will result in the loss of the decimal.

Comment: If those are changed to float, other errors come up with the print statements and the % modulus I think. What else would I need to change?

Comment: This website [link](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/printf-format-strings.html) talks about formatting strings using the printf method.  According to that website, your string formats should be %.1f